# Hadoop cluster Http port for name node is not working

Tags: hadoop

HI I have setup a psuedo hadoop cluster in a vm. while giving jps i can see datanode, nomenode , jobtacker, tasktracker every thing is running but if i want to see the cluster details using web ui http port of name node 50070 using the ip:50070 i am getting below error 
on browser

```
 No route to host
 Description: No route to host
```

can any one tell me if i missing something in any configuration file like for web ui where i can check?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you accessing it from remote machine?

Comment: yes vm is running on other m/c and i am accessing on other

Answer (score 0):

Probably a network error than hadoop specific.
Can you try this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/no-route-to-host-error-and-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:500070/dfshealth.jsp` are you trying to access like this from the same VM ? if from your local machine, first get the ipaddress of the vm machine by `ifconfig` and ping it from local machine like this,  `ping <vm-ipaddress>`
If the ping is successful by `ICMP` and `No loss of packets`. Then your network is firewall free and you can access the hadoop web ui from local machine.
If you are still not able to access, then check the @Tom Sebastian shared link to disable the firewall and other stuff.
This is surely not the hadoop related issue.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply and i agree its not the problem with hadoop. ping IpAddress is working fine no loss of packets as well as i refered that link shared by  @Tom Sebastian and clear all iptables rules following the commands shown in link but still if i do IP:50070 its showing no route to host.

Comment: and one more thing that vm is not having ui i mean its having only console

Comment: please share the code of `core-site.xml` and if firewall is off and ping is working fine.. you can access the Hadoop UI from your local machine. Make sure that both machines are in same network.